# Is it possible to iteratively collect each partition of rdd?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo, rdd

I have a rdd which I need to store in mongoDB.

I tried use rdd.map to write each row of the rdd to mongoDB, using pymongo. But I encountered pickle error as it seems that pickling pymongo object to the workers is not supported.

Hence, I do a `rdd.collect()` to get the rdd to driver, and write it to mongoDB.

Is it possible to iteratively collect each partition of the rdd instead? This will minimize the changes of out of memory at the driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use [`RDD.toLocalIterator()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.toLocalIterator). You should remember though that it doesn't come for free. Each partition will require a separate job so you should consider persisting your data before you use it.